# Cannot correctly publish react/styled components to npm built with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` for my project which is a component library that uses react and styled-components and I want to publish the project on `npm`.

I've a few questions that are bothering me and resulting in errors when installed as a package in other projects.

1. Which directory should be published - `src` or `dist`?
2. If I publish `src` then I get this error -

```
./node_modules/packagename/src/components/atoms/Button/index.jsx 6:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export const TextButton = ({ children, ...props }) => (
>    <StyledTextButton {...props}>{children}</StyledTextButton>
| )
|
```

3. If I publish `dist` then I get this error -

```
Can't resolve `packagename` in 'project/src'
```

so it's looking inside the `src` of the project where I'm installing the library package

So I found out, we need to add `"main": "dist/index.js"` but the `dist` folder has `index.html` at the root and hashed js file names inside `static/js` folder

So what is the correct procedure to publish a package built using create-react-app and styled-components?